# React Hot Loader doesn't update view for 'requireAuth' wrapped component

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, redux, react-hot-loader

I'm diving into 'react-redux-webpack' world for the last couple of days, willing to try it out and create a template for login.

I have injected React Hot Loader for fast view updates to work, but it updates only the view for unwrapped in 'requireAuth' part.

I'm using `componentWillUpdate` and `componentWillMount` to detect login changes. So I wonder whats the reason React Hot Loader isn't able to push changes to view? Since I see that new data (after its changed/saved in IDE) is pulled to browser (inside chrome network inspector).

I would appreciate any input, since I tried my thoughts already, but obviously two days in redux world is not yet enough to figure that out fast ))

here is 'require authentication' component I've built with help of tutorial which works for its purpose grate:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux';

export default function (ComposedComponent) {
  class Authentication extends Component {

    // to receive access to ROUTER >>>
    static contextTypes = {
      router: React.PropTypes.object
    };

    componentWillMount() {
      if (!this.props.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/');
        alert("Please, SIGN IN to continue!");
      }
    };

    componentWillUpdate(nextProps) {
      if (!nextProps.authenticated) {
        this.context.router.push('/');
        alert("Come back soon :)");
      }
    }

    render() {
      return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} />
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {authenticated: state.authenticated};
  }

  return connect(mapStateToProps)(Authentication);
}
```

And view with wrapped 'resource' component, which available only after sign in:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import {Router, Route, browserHistory} from 'react-router';


import requireAuth from './components/require_authentication';
import App from './components/app';
import Resources from './components/resources';
import reducers from './reducers';

const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware()(createStore);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={createStoreWithMiddleware(reducers)}>
    <Router history={browserHistory}>

      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="resources" component={requireAuth(Resources)} />
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Which file are you editing?

Comment: @DanAbramov I'm building a template with middlewates and high order components. The problem is that hot loader doesn't update view for resources used with authentication HOC (https://github.com/A1ex5andr/redux-test/blob/dev-hot-middleware/src/reducers/authenticatoin.js)

Comment: Things are a bit turbulent right now. I probably won’t look into this because I’m working on a complete revamp of React Hot Loader in https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-boilerplate/pull/61. It should handle most other use cases much better but React Router support is still work in progress. I’ll link to your repo from https://github.com/gaearon/react-hot-loader/issues/249 so I check back on this before shipping.

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks a lot :)